# GCP - Get ID token in environment-independent way

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-authentication

I have an application that must verify the identity of its caller. For this I need ID tokens (the JWTs from Google's OpenID Connect implementation) from each client calling the service.

I would like to write client code that works both locally using the default user credentials—for testing and development—and on a Compute Engine instance in production. The [official Python auth SDK](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python) generally does a good job of handling those cases and saving me the trouble of checking the environment, e.g. I can just call `google.auth.default` and it figures out where to get credentials.

**However**, that `google.auth` package only seems to be able to give me *auth tokens*, not *ID tokens* in an environment-independent way. Here is what I tried:

```
import google.auth
from google.auth.transport import requests

credentials, project = google.auth.default(scopes=["openid"])
req = requests.Request()
credentials.refresh(req)

print(credentials.id_token)
```

This works on my laptop with my default credentials, but on the Compute Engine instance I instead get an error `AttributeError: 'Credentials' object has no attribute 'id_token'`

According to [this page in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/verifying-instance-identity), you are supposed to fetch an ID token for an instance by requesting it from the metadata server...

```
import requests

audience = 'service_identifier'
metadata_server_token_url = 'http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience='
token_request_url = metadata_server_token_url + audience
token_request_headers = {'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'}

token_response = requests.get(token_request_url, headers=token_request_headers)
jwt = token_response.content.decode("utf-8")
print(jwt)
```

I don't want to do that. I don't want to manually check the environment. The SDK is supposed to handle that complexity for me. Shouldn't there be a way to leverage the `google-auth` SDK to generate an ID token in an environment-independent way?

EDIT 1: Why I need this

The application is based on Cloud Functions, and it returns highly sensitive data. Only a specific set of subjects—some trusted devs and services—should be able to access that data. So, the cloud functions must verify the ID of the caller (user or service account) using an ID token signed by Google. Specifically, I need to know the `sub` claim, the "subject" in the JWT. It is effectively the same issue that the IAM features are meant to solve, documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access). However, I cannot use these because they are still in *beta*. So, I'm writing identity checks manually into the cloud functions for the time being.

Comment: I have updated with more details. Basically, I need the `sub` claim in the JWT in order to identify the caller. I see that the construction of the JWT is parameterized by the `aud`, which must be passed when obtaining an ID token from the metadata server. If the SDK cannot currently handle this, it seems like a sensible feature request: a new method that takes the audience parameter and returns an ID token...

Comment: Did you find a way to do this, Andy?

Comment: @AndyCarlson Did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think I have an answer to this question. I could always get it to work locally or in the cloud, the trick was to find a way of combining the two.  I colleague of mine actually showed me how to do this and I just wanted to share this with others who are looking for a solution.

```
import google.auth
from   google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession, Request
from   google.oauth2.id_token import fetch_id_token
import requests

def GetIdToken(audience):
  credentials, _ = google.auth.default()
  session = AuthorizedSession(credentials)
  request = Request(session)
  credentials.refresh(request)
  if hasattr(credentials, "id_token"):
    return credentials.id_token
  return fetch_id_token(request, audience)

def ProcessPayload(url, payload):
  # Get the ID Token
  id_token = GetIdToken(url)
  # Process post request
  headers        = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {id_token}'}
  response       = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
```